# How to display more than 3 images in a row for eshop

Tags: html, web, bootstrap-4, frontend

I downloaded a code to practice making an eshop and i want to display 4 products instead of 3 products per row. I tried different ways of doing it but all have failed so far. I also tried to delete some of the lines to see if anything changed but I didnt get the result that i wanted. If someone could help i would appreciate it a lot. This is the code

```
   <section class="product-shop spad">
        <div  class="container">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="product-list">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="product-item">
                                    <div class="pi-pic">
                                        <img src="img/products/product-1.jpg" alt="">
                                        <div class="sale pp-sale">Sale</div>
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <i class="icon_heart_alt"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="w-icon active"><a href="#"><i class="icon_bag_alt"></i></a></li>
                                            <li class="quick-view"><a href="#">+ Quick View</a></li>
                                            <li class="w-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-random"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pi-text">
                                        <div class="catagory-name">Towel</div>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h5>Pure Pineapple</h5>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="product-price">
                                            $14.00
                                            <span>$35.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="product-item">
                                    <div class="pi-pic">
                                        <img src="img/products/product-2.jpg" alt="">
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <i class="icon_heart_alt"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="w-icon active"><a href="#"><i class="icon_bag_alt"></i></a></li>
                                            <li class="quick-view"><a href="#">+ Quick View</a></li>
                                            <li class="w-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-random"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pi-text">
                                        <div class="catagory-name">Coat</div>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h5>Guangzhou sweater</h5>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="product-price">
                                            $13.00
                                            <span>$35.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="product-item">
                                    <div class="pi-pic">
                                        <img src="img/products/product-3.jpg" alt="">
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <i class="icon_heart_alt"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="w-icon active"><a href="#"><i class="icon_bag_alt"></i></a></li>
                                            <li class="quick-view"><a href="#">+ Quick View</a></li>
                                            <li class="w-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-random"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pi-text">
                                        <div class="catagory-name">Shoes</div>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h5>Guangzhou sweater</h5>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="product-price">
                                            $34.00
                                            <span>$35.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="product-item">
                                    <div class="pi-pic">
                                        <img src="img/products/product-4.jpg" alt="">
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <i class="icon_heart_alt"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="w-icon active"><a href="#"><i class="icon_bag_alt"></i></a></li>
                                            <li class="quick-view"><a href="#">+ Quick View</a></li>
                                            <li class="w-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-random"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pi-text">
                                        <div class="catagory-name">Coat</div>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h5>Microfiber Wool Scarf</h5>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="product-price">
                                            $64.00
                                            <span>$35.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="product-item">
                                    <div class="pi-pic">
                                        <img src="img/products/product-5.jpg" alt="">
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <i class="icon_heart_alt"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="w-icon active"><a href="#"><i class="icon_bag_alt"></i></a></li>
                                            <li class="quick-view"><a href="#">+ Quick View</a></li>
                                            <li class="w-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-random"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pi-text">
                                        <div class="catagory-name">Shoes</div>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h5>Men's Painted Hat</h5>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="product-price">
                                            $44.00
                                            <span>$35.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="product-item">
                                    <div class="pi-pic">
                                        <img src="img/products/product-6.jpg" alt="">
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <i class="icon_heart_alt"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="w-icon active"><a href="#"><i class="icon_bag_alt"></i></a></li>
                                            <li class="quick-view"><a href="#">+ Quick View</a></li>
                                            <li class="w-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-random"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pi-text">
                                        <div class="catagory-name">Shoes</div>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h5>Converse Shoes</h5>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="product-price">
                                            $34.00
                                            <span>$35.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="product-item">
                                    <div class="pi-pic">
                                        <img src="img/products/product-7.jpg" alt="">
                                        <div class="sale pp-sale">Sale</div>
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <i class="icon_heart_alt"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="w-icon active"><a href="#"><i class="icon_bag_alt"></i></a></li>
                                            <li class="quick-view"><a href="#">+ Quick View</a></li>
                                            <li class="w-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-random"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pi-text">
                                        <div class="catagory-name">Towel</div>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h5>Pure Pineapple</h5>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="product-price">
                                            $64.00
                                            <span>$35.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="product-item">
                                    <div class="pi-pic">
                                        <img src="img/products/product-8.jpg" alt="">
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <i class="icon_heart_alt"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="w-icon active"><a href="#"><i class="icon_bag_alt"></i></a></li>
                                            <li class="quick-view"><a href="#">+ Quick View</a></li>
                                            <li class="w-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-random"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pi-text">
                                        <div class="catagory-name">Coat</div>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h5>2 Layer Windbreaker</h5>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="product-price">
                                            $44.00
                                            <span>$35.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="product-item">
                                    <div class="pi-pic">
                                        <img src="img/products/product-9.jpg" alt="">
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <i class="icon_heart_alt"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="w-icon active"><a href="#"><i class="icon_bag_alt"></i></a></li>
                                            <li class="quick-view"><a href="#">+ Quick View</a></li>
                                            <li class="w-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-random"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pi-text">
                                        <div class="catagory-name">Shoes</div>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h5>Converse Shoes</h5>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="product-price">
                                            $34.00
                                            <span>$35.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
       </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: Try changing this line `<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">`  to `<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">`, this makes one column span 3 units (1/4) of the whole grid (whole width is 12 units).

Comment: @SamuelOlekšák you are correct BUT this reduces the size of the pictures. I want to have the same size but more products on the row

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's grid ruffly works as follows:

A group of a maximum of 12

(columns)

```
<div class="col"> ****your content**** </div>
```

must be the immediate children of a

(one row)

```
<div class="row"> ****your group of columns**** </div>
```

and a row can only be the immediate child of a

(a container)

```
<div class="container"> ****your row with columns inside it**** </div>
```

****container>row>col****
***(maximum 12 cols within a row)***

PLEASE NOTE: 9 cannot be divided by 4 unless you break one of your products into fractions :) (obvious but must be mentioned).

Since the grid is considered 12 columns from left to right, by telling the col is supposed to be the width of 3 cols from left to right; you get 4 columns per line:

```css
body, a{font-size:0.3em!important;text-align: center;}
.pi-pic{text-align: center;}
.pi-pic img{display: inline-block;width: 50%; height:50%;}
.blue{background-color: #7474b2;border: solid 1px #fff;font-size: 16px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CodePen - A Pen by Lancelot Pierre Blaine</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div  class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-3 blue">1</div>
<div class="col-3 blue">2</div>
<div class="col-3 blue">3</div>
<div class="col-3 blue">4</div>
<div class="col-3 blue">5</div>
<div class="col-3 blue">6</div>
<div class="col-3 blue">7</div>
<div class="col-3 blue">8</div>
<div class="col-3 blue">9</div>
<div class="col-3 blue">10</div>
<div class="col-3 blue">11</div>
<div class="col-3 blue">12</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***ADDITIONAL INFO:***

[>>Bootstrap 4.6 docs<<](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/)

====>[a codepen with your original content in it (linked dummy images)](https://codepen.io/LancelotPierreBlaine/pen/NWpwzzv)